# Can I output the results of the strate command to LaTeX?

Tags: latex, stata

When using Stata's [`strate`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?strate) command, is it possible to export its output to a `LaTeX` table?

In a similar vein as, for instance, the *community-contributed* [`estout`](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/index.html) family of commands can do.

Comment: Have you tried Est2Tex? You can search/download it within Stata directly.

Comment: I did give it a shot. Running `est2vec` after `strate` gives me an error though: `last estimates not found`.

Comment: The answer won't work for you. `est2tex` (SSC) is, as documented, for estimation results and `strate` is not an e-class command. End of that story. I don't have a more positive suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved by using the `output()` option of the `strate` command and `esttab`.

Consider the following toy example:

```
webuse diet, clear
stset dox, origin(time doe) id(id) scale(365.25) fail(fail==1 3 13)

stsplit ageband, at(40(10)70) after(time=dob) trim

preserve
tempfile myfile
strate ageband, per(1000) output(`myfile')
use `myfile', clear
mkmat *, matrix(A)
restore

esttab matrix(A), title("Summary results") ///
                  mlabels(, none) ///
                  varlabels(r1 " " r2 " " r3 " ")                                                                   

Summary results
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  ageband           _D           _Y        _Rate       _Lower       _Upper
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       40            6     .9070062      6.61517     2.971936     14.72457
                       50           18     2.107042     8.542783     5.382317     13.55906
                       60           22     1.493292     14.73255     9.700656     22.37457
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `tex` option of `esttab` will then produce the desired `LaTeX` output:

```
esttab matrix(A), title("Summary results") ///
                  mlabels(, none) ///
                  varlabels(r1 " " r2 " " r3 " ") ///
                  tex

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Summary results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &     ageband&          \_D&          \_Y&       \_Rate&      \_Lower&      \_Upper\\
\hline
            &          40&           6&    .9070062&     6.61517&    2.971936&    14.72457\\
            &          50&          18&    2.107042&    8.542783&    5.382317&    13.55906\\
            &          60&          22&    1.493292&    14.73255&    9.700656&    22.37457\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```